# additional toolbar - one click short cuts

Tags: unity, windows-xp

Is there is any way to create a "toolbar" of folder containing short cuts?
By short cuts I mean - web, catalogues, radio, programs, docs in that folder
At win xp I could create on each screen edge a toolbar by simply puling a folder to it. Now I am at ubuntu/unity and, well... its like a BIG step back for me.
"System is only background for programs"
Sorry for my pov but easy way to run PC is when you have everything under ONE click.

Comment: I have no clue what you're talking about.
Could you elaborate a bit more on this "toolbar" thing (it might be useful for other users with similar problems).
Do you mean something like ph0t0nix posted a few seconds ago??

Answer (score 1):

You could try and install [Cairo Dock](http://glx-dock.org/), this will give you a bar (at the bottom by default), which is very customisable and has options like this: [image].

Answer (score 0):

The Panel is the toolbar at top and bottom in the GNOME UI. To get it, install *gnome-shell* from Ubuntu Software Centre and use *gnome classic desktop* (by selecting it from the login menu) then you can move the panel as described in the other answers. Then, you can right-click on the Panel to add launchers for apps.